# Java - Is this good practice?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm designing a simple car rental system and was wondering whether I was using good practice for the design. Basically, I have a showroom arraylist, which stores all rental cars (new objects). Inside each car object is an arraylist for the availability of that car for that month. The availability comprises of 31 values (corresponding to each day in that month), either 0 or 1 (available). They are initially set to 1 until a car is booked for that day. Is there another way of incorporating availability?

```
ArrayList<Car> showroom = new ArrayList<Car>();

ArrayList<Integer> Available1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> Available2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

setAllDatesAvailable(Available1);
setAllDatesAvailable(Available2);

Car number1 = new Car(objectitems, ... , Available1);
showroom.add(number1);
Car number2 = new Car(objectitems, ... , Available2);
showroom.add(number2);
```

> //booking process

```
setAllDatesAvailable(ArrayList Array) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
      Array.add(1);
}
```

NB:

- i'm not worried about timestamps, assume that the car is booked for
  the whole day
- assume that the system is only for a single month of 31 days

Comment: Knock the door of [codereview.se] with this question.

Comment: start by changing the declarations to List, the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some improvements that I would suggest for your code: -

1. First, follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Variable name should start with lowercase letters. `Available` -> `available`, or even better, `availableDates` to match the purpose of your `List`
2. Always use *Generic Type* collections.

   ```
   setAllDatesAvailable(ArrayList Array)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   setAllDatesAvailable(ArrayList<Integer> array);
   ```
3. Use `Interface` as your Reference types. You should declare your list as: -

   ```
   List<Integer> availableDates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ```

   Same thing also in the formal parameters in your methods, as shown in comment by @Alex.
4. Choose meaningful name for your variables.

   ```
   Car number1 = ...; <-- // makes no sense to reader
   ```

   change it to: -

   ```
   Car car1 = ...;
   ```
5. As far as possible, try to name your `formal` parameters same as of your `actual` parameters.

   ```
   setAllDatesAvailable(ArrayList<Integer> array);
   ```

   should better be declared as: -

   ```
   setAllDatesAvailable(List<Integer> availableDates);
   ```

After all these changes, you can look forward to improvise the functionality of your code, which @DNA has very nicely written in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13277427/1679863).

Comment: Use also the `List` interface for parameters in `setAllDatesAvailable(List<Integer> availableDates);` or a `Collection` if you are just traversing it.

Comment: @Alex.. Oh yeah. I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler to record availability as an array of booleans (or ints). There's no need to use `ArrayList` for fixed-length records like this (the main benefit of `ArrayList` is that it can grow dynamically).

I think it would be better to use the default value of boolean or int to indicate availability - then you won't need to explicitly initialize the array at all. For boolean this would mean recording bookings not availability:

```
    boolean[] booked = new boolean[31];
    System.out.println(booked[0]);  // false
```

This also highlights a potential confusion - days of the month often get confused in software because of zero-indexing, so you need to be clear whether the 1st day of the month is 0 or 1.

It would be better and more Object-Oriented to store (and initialise, if necessary) the bookings/availability *inside* the Car object, and provide methods on the Car object to manipulate that data as required.

Comment: +1 for the boolean array, no need for a List for this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below maybe - I'd avoid passing around naked collections. LocalDate is in the joda library. Default scope on Car is deliberate and assuming these are in the same package but the client is not:

```
public class Showroom {

    private Collection<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public boolean isCarAvailable(Car car, LocalDate day) {
        return car.isAvailable(day);
    }

    public void bookCarOnDate(Car car, LocalDate day) throws IlegalStateException {
          car.book(day);
    }

    public Collection<Car> getCars() {
          return Collection.unmodifiableCollection(cars);
    }
}

class Car {

    private Map<LocalDate, Boolean> dayAvailability = new HashMap<LocalDate, Boolean>();

    Car() {
        //add other private attributes
        //don't provide setters for these - create new whenever modified so don't leak 
        //state and thread safety
    }

    boolean isAvailable(LocalDate day) {
       return dayAvailability.get(day) != null && dayAvailability.get(day);
    }

    void book(LocalDate day) {
     if (isAvailable(day)) {
         dayAvailability.put(car, true);
     else {
         throw IllegalStateException("Car "+car+" not available for booking on date "+localDate);
     }
}
```